# Focal Length Calculation

Tags: optics, laser, geometric-optics, fiber-optics

Although I research in the internet, I couldn't find detailed answer. I have a question and I want to make sure from the answer.

The ligth is coming from a fiber laser source and focused on a surface. I want to calculate focal lengths.
[image]

Comment: +0 Welcome to physics SE! This question has no answer, if you do not define two things. a) $d_{source}\neq d_1$ and b) diverging angle $\theta_{source}$ which your laser may provide in its manual as an FWHM angle. Adding this information will earn you +1

Comment: The distance between the source and lens1 is d1. About diverging angle, I don't know since I will be design such a system and I can be determined after learning this stuff. For now, let's just say angle θsource.

Comment: Improve your question by asking about a physics concept. You already learned focal length is related to making a perfect point source to a perfect parallel beam. Read about this geometric  optics. Please feal free to ask specific questions about imperfect point sources - real sources.

Answer (score 1):

Focal length of Lens 2 is $d_5$, because parallel rays converge at a distance of d5 from lens 2.
Focal length of lens 1 is $d_1$ beacuse  diverging rays become parallel to optical axis at a distance of d1.
Focal length of system is $d_2+d_3+d_4+d_5$ FROM LENS 1.

Comment: +1 Yes, $f_2=d_5$. However I see from the sketch $d_1\neq d_{source}$ If it is also equal, than you are right.

Comment: I guess focal length of lens 1 is not d1, it should be back focal length. "The lens equation expresses the quantitative relationship between the object distance (do), the image distance (di), and the focal length (f). The equation is stated as follows: 1/f1=(1/di)+(1/d0)" For such a system, I guess we need such a calculation.

Comment: Also, assume that I know  the f1 and f2. How can I determine d2+d3+d4 to focus my ray to the sample?

Comment: what do you mean by back focal length.As per lens formula the MAGNITUDE of f remains same no matter direction of consideration

Comment: Also f1 is d1. View the focal lenth for lens 1 using principle of reversibility.

Comment: Please look at this real lenses. They have focal length and back focal length. http://www.thorlabs.de/newgrouppage9.cfm?objectgroup_id=3279&pn=LA1289-A

Comment: I looked at it, and found out they are the same thing  for a SINGLE lens. For a system of lens Front focal length is distance from first lens and back focal length is distance from last or rear lens within the system.

Comment: Okey, let's say I found d1=f1. And d5=f2. How can I calculate d2+d3+d4?

Comment: You may select distance in parallel beam path arbitarly in geometric optics. Think about the lines in your diagram of a perfect parallel beam path: nothing will change the parallel lines until they refracted by a lens.

Comment: About lens 2, I'm planning to use aspheric lens in this system. We know the focal length but there is term called working distance. Do you know what is the difference between them?

Comment: Your posted company Thorlabs has good online ressoures concerning working distance WC and focal length f. Post a separate question after studying these resources.